# How to extract just the random effects part of the formula from lme4

Tags: r, lme4

Let us say I have fitted a model such

```
mymodel <- lmer(Y~X1+(1|fac1)+(1|fac2),mydata)
```

How can I extract just the random effects part of the formula (`(1|fac1)+(1|fac2)`) ?

I know I can do

```
formula(mymodel)[-2]
```

but this just returns `X1 + (1| fac1) + (1| fac2)`

I know I could do something with regex but I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: You can try: `stringr::str_extract_all(formula(mymodel),"\\(.*\\)")` and drop what you don't need.

Comment: Related: [Extract components from mixed model (lme4) formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049440/extract-components-from-mixed-model-lme4-formula); from the link: `lme4:::findbars(f1)`

Answer (score 11):

### findbars

The lme4 package provides `findbars`:

```
library(lme4)

fo <- Y~X1+(1|fac1)+(1|fac2)

findbars(fo)
## [[1]]
## 1 | fac1
##
## [[2]]
## 1 | fac2
```

If character strings are needed  we can use the following.  `deparse1` will handle certain uncommon cases that `deparse` fails at but `deparse` will mostly work as an alternative if it is necessary that this work in versions of R earlier than R 4.0.0.

```
sapply(findbars(fo), deparse1)
## [1] "1 | fac1" "1 | fac2"
```

If the desired result is the RHS of the formula but without the fixed effects terms then we can reconstitute the above by adding back the parentheses and using `reformulate`.  Omit [[2]] if a formula object is desired.  Discussion above regarding `deparse1` applies here too.

```
reformulate(sprintf("(%s)", sapply(findbars(fo), deparse1)))[[2]]
## (1 | fac1) + (1 | fac2)
```

### terms/labels

Another way to get character result is to use `labels` which will extract them from `terms` .  Use `reformulate`, as above, if a formula is desired.  This does not use any packages.

```
X <- grep("|", labels(terms(fo)), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
X
## [1] "1 | fac1" "1 | fac2"
```

As above, the formula and right hand side of it can be generated from `X` like this:

```
reformulate(sprintf("(%s)", X))
reformulate(sprintf("(%s)", X))[[2]]
```

### getTerms

Another approach is to use `getTerms` from [Terms of a sum in a R expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300717/terms-of-a-sum-in-a-r-expression/53300817#53300817)  This short function recursively walks the formula to extract the terms. It does not use any packages.

```
XX <- grep("|", sapply(getTerms(fo[[3]]), deparse1), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
XX
## [1] "(1 | fac1)" "(1 | fac2)"
```

The formula and right hand side of it can be generated like this:

```
reformulate(XX)
reformulate(XX)[[2]]
```

Answer (score 5):

No regex required , however, it's still string manipulation.

```
# stringsplit the output of your formula()
# remove the first entry 
# remove spaces with gsub()
# paste it back together

inp <- "X1 + (1| fac1) + (1| fac2)"

paste(gsub(" ", "", unlist(strsplit(inp, "+", fixed = T))[-1], fixed = T), 
      collapse = " + ")

# [1] "(1|fac1) + (1|fac2)"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that may not generalise:

```
# This model may not make much sense, just for reproducibility
mymodel <- lmer(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+(1|Species) + (1|Petal.Width),iris)    
stringr::str_extract_all(formula(mymodel),"\\(.*\\)")[3]
    [[1]]
    [1] "(1 | Species) + (1 | Petal.Width)"
```

To "automatically" drop all empty elements:

```
purrr::compact(stringr::str_extract_all(formula(mymodel),"\\(.*\\)"))
[[1]]
[1] "(1 | Species) + (1 | Petal.Width)"
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing G Grthendieck's answer I realise I'm probably reinventing the wheel, but here's a way to get the random effects parts out of a model without using regex. It uses recursion to examine each call in the formula's AST and keeps only those in parentheses, which it then rebuilds into an expression. I may be wrong, but this feels safer than switching between character strings and language objects. It could be modified to pull out only `|` calls.

```r
get_random_effects <- function(mod)
{
  rip_formula <- function(form) 
  {
    
    if(rlang::is_formula(form)) form <- as.list(form)[-c(1:2)][[1]]
    if(is.call(form)) {
      call_list <- as.list(form)
      if(as.character(call_list[[1]]) == "+") 
        return(unlist(lapply(call_list[-1], rip_formula)))
      if(as.character(call_list[[1]]) == "(") 
        return(form)
     } 
  }
  
  re_list <- rip_formula(formula(mod))
  while(length(re_list) > 2) 
    re_list <- c(as.call(list(bquote(`+`), re_list[1:2])), re_list[-(1:2)])
  as.call(list(bquote(`+`), re_list[[1]], re_list[[2]]))
}
```

So it's now as easy as:

```
get_random_effects(mymodel)
#> (1 | fac1) + (1 | fac2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [insight-package](https://easystats.github.io/insight/) to access various model information, like formula, predictors, data etc. *insight* provides type-safe "generics" that work for many different models. In this case, you could use `find_formula()` or `find_random()`:

```r
library(insight)
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
sleepstudy$mygrp <- sample(1:5, size = 180, replace = TRUE)
sleepstudy$mysubgrp <- NA
for (i in 1:5) {
  filter_group <- sleepstudy$mygrp == i
  sleepstudy$mysubgrp[filter_group] <-
    sample(1:30, size = sum(filter_group), replace = TRUE)
}

m <- lmer(
  Reaction ~ Days + (1 | mygrp / mysubgrp) + (1 | Subject),
  data = sleepstudy
)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

find_formula(m)
#> $conditional
#> Reaction ~ Days
#> 
#> $random
#> $random[[1]]
#> ~1 | mysubgrp:mygrp
#> 
#> $random[[2]]
#> ~1 | mygrp
#> 
#> $random[[3]]
#> ~1 | Subject

find_random(m)
#> $random
#> [1] "mysubgrp:mygrp" "mygrp"          "Subject"       
#> 

find_random(m, split_nested = TRUE)
#> $random
#> [1] "mysubgrp" "mygrp"    "Subject" 

find_random(m, split_nested = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)
#> [1] "mysubgrp" "mygrp"    "Subject"
```

`find_formula()` and `find_random()` also work for models with zero-inflation part that have random effects, e.g. for models from the *glmmTMB* or *brms* packages. The "counterpart" to find possible random slopes would be [`find_random_slopes()`](https://easystats.github.io/insight/reference/find_random_slopes.html).