# Extract character elements from vectors

Tags: r, regex, string, character

I have a set of character vectors:

```
a <- "bmi + ch | study"
b <- "bmi * ch | study"
c <- "bmi * ch - 1 | study"
d <- "bmi * ch + 0 | study"
e <- "bmi:ch + 0 | study"
```

In this example, I want to extract the two strings `"bmi"` and `"ch"`, i.e. the desired output is `c("bmi", "ch")`

The strings above are just examples; the character elements to be extracted can be anything else other than `ch` and `bmi`. I'm looking for a general solution, without hard-coding.

I have tried `unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(a, "bmi|ch"))`. However, here I manually define the pattern `"bmi|ch"` to achieve the desired output. Thus, it's not a general solution.

Comment: Could you add some sample data to work with? Are these formulae want you want to extract from?

Comment: @NelsonGon, that's the fully reproducible sample data `(a,b,...e)` vectors in the question. I also have provided desired output. I additionally have provided what I have tried and explained why it is NOT what I'm looking for.

Comment: You said you want a solution that doesn't use the string you're searching for. I'm not sure how to define this answer. Is it true that there is only one 3 char string and one two char string in all possible solutions? Then regex to look for a 3 or 2 char string? If you're look for something that is scaleable, you could use `paste` but you would still have to say what you're looking for. For example, `tofind <- paste(c("bmi","ch"), collapse="|")` and  `unlist(str_extract_all(a, tofind))`, where `a` is a list or vector of the strings you're assessing.

Comment: Maybe maybe this could be a start: [Extract components from mixed model (lme4) formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049440/extract-components-from-mixed-model-lme4-formula)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume the vector v defined in the Note at the end.  Then we can lapply over it  using the indicated function.  If the number of variables is always the same you could alternately use sapply giving a matrix.

```
lapply(sub("\\|.*", "", v), function(x) all.vars(parse(text = x)))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[2]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[3]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[4]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[5]]
[1] "bmi" "ch"
```

### Note

```
a <- "bmi + ch | study"
b <- "bmi * ch | study"
c <- "bmi * ch - 1 | study"
d <- "bmi * ch + 0 | study"
e <- "bmi:ch + 0 | study"
v <- c(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: In case of interest, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70551967/16762740) is a related question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more complicated and not efficient. I will just leave it here in case someone may find it interesting.

```
vecs<-list(a,b, c,d,e)
split_me<-Map(function(x) gsub("([a-z].*[a-z])(\\W.*)","\\1",x, 

perl=TRUE), vecs)
 lapply(split_me, function(x) 
  unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\s", "",x), "[+*:]")))
```

Result

```
[[1]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[2]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[3]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[4]]
[1] "bmi" "ch" 

[[5]]
[1] "bmi" "ch"
```

Data

```
a <- "bmi + ch | study"
b <- "bmi * ch | study"
c <- "bmi * ch - 1 | study"
d <- "bmi * ch + 0 | study"
e <- "bmi:ch + 0 | study"
vecs<-list(a,b, c,d,e)
```