# Dropping partially overlapping parts of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, regex, string, character

I wonder if it might be possible to drop the parts in `n1` character vector that ***partially overlap*** with elements in `f1` formula.

For example, in `n1`, we see `"chyes"`&`"bmi:chyes"` partially overlap with `ch` in `f1`.

Thus in the `desired_output`, we want to drop the `"ch"` part of them. Because other elements in `n1` either fully overlap with an element in `f1` (ex. `bmi`) or don't exist in `f1` (ex. `intrcpt`), we leave them unchanged.

I have tried the following solution, but can't get my desired output.

Is obtaining my `desired_output` possible in BASE `R` or tidyvesrse?

```
f1 <- yi~ bmi*ch

n1 <- c("intrcpt","bmi","chyes","bmi:chyes")

desired_output <- c("intrcpt","bmi","yes","bmi:yes")

### Current unsuccessful solution:
foo <- function(fmla, vec) {
  
  v1 <- all.vars(fmla)
  v2 <- setdiff(vec, v1)
  v1 <- paste0('^', v1)
  v3 <- sub(paste(v1, collapse = "|"), "", v2)
  vec[vec %in% v2] <- v3
  vec 
}
### EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(f1, n1)
# "intrcpt"   "bmi"       "chyes"     "bmi:chyes"
```

Comment: You can not have `yes` by itself. You have to determine the variable that yes comes from and that is the `ch` variable. Unless you use numerical variables

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is your end goal? Seems that this is an intermedite process. What do you want to do in the end? add/drop terms??

Comment: Laslty could you give the data that produces the `n1` vector?

Comment: @Onyambu, this is a reproducible programming question. I appreciate a programming answer.

Comment: What is your end goal? I have seen youve asked multiple questions with regards to formula. You might be doing something wrong. The intermediate steps might be unnecessary and might be unwelcomed after all. Probably there is a single function out there that can transform what you have to the end goal without the steps you are going through

Comment: @Onyambu, I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70701629/16762740) is of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does what you want, but I agree with @Onyambu that it is worth considering whether your underlying problem actually necessitates string manipulation.

```r
f <- function(fm, nm) {
  vars <- vapply(attr(terms(fm), "variables"), deparse, "")[-1L]
  subpat <- paste0(gsub("([()])", "\\\\\\1", vars), collapse = "|")
  l <- rapply(strsplit(nm, ":"), sub, how = "list",
              perl = TRUE,
              pattern = sprintf("^(?!(%1$s)$)(%1$s)(.+)$", subpat),
              replacement = "\\3")
  vapply(l, paste0, "", collapse = ":")
}

fm1 <- yi ~ bmi * ch
nm1 <- c("intrcpt", "bmi", "chyes", "bmi:chyes")
f(fm1, nm1)
```

```
[1] "intrcpt" "bmi"     "yes"     "bmi:yes"
```

```r
fm2 <- yi ~ bmi * factor(ch)
nm2 <- c("intrcpt", "bmi", "factor(ch)yes", "bmi:factor(ch)yes")
f(fm2, nm2)
```

```
[1] "intrcpt" "bmi"     "yes"     "bmi:yes"
```

```r
fm3 <- gi ~ 0 + time:pub_type + time_wk_whn + time_wk_btw
nm3 <- c("time_wk_whn", "time_wk_btw", "timePost-test 1:pub_typejournal", "timePost-test 2:pub_typejournal")
f(fm3, nm3)
```

```
[1] "time_wk_whn"         "time_wk_btw"        
[3] "Post-test 1:journal" "Post-test 2:journal"
```