# Replace part of the output of lm() function in Base R

Tags: r, function, statistics, regression, lm

Object `res1` is a regression function from the `metafor` package. Object `res2` is a regression function from the `stats` R base.

I was wondering if it might be possible to get the `vcov()` of `res1` and substitute it for `vcov()` of `res2`?

Below is my unsuccessful solution.

```
# An Example:
library(metafor)

dat2 <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=waward, n1i=wtotal, ci=maward,
n2i=mtotal, data=dat.bornmann2007)

res1 <- rma.mv(yi ~ 0+type, vi, random = ~ 1 | study/obs, data=dat2)

res2 <- lm(yi ~ 0+type, data = dat2)

vcov(res2) <- vcov(res1) ## apparently this won't work!
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? ie anytime you want `vcov` just do `vcov(res1)`

Comment: @Onyambu, I want to replace the values of `vcov(res2)`  with `vcov(res1)` such that when we do `vcov(res2)` the values of `vcov(res1)` are outputted.

Comment: `vcov(res1)` is a value computed on the fly. It is not storred anywhere. So no need to store it. Just ensure that anytime you want to compute the `vcov(res2)` just compute `vcov(res1)`

Comment: @Onyambu, do you agree with or can you show the approach described by user2554330, below?

Comment: Yes, ther approach is correct.  You could do that only if you need `vcoc` without further analysis

Comment: What else do you need from res1 apart from its `vcov` matrix?

Comment: @Onyambu, I need the coefficients but that's very simple.

Comment: So you need `coef(res1)` and `vcov(res1)`. Anything else? What of from `res2` what do you need?

Comment: @Onyambu, I need the following two (the first one works OK but `vcov` doesn't): `res2$coefficients <- unlist(data.frame(t(res1$b))) ; vcov(res2) <- vcov(res1)`

Comment: My question is what do you need from `res2`? why do you need the `lm` model. Why not just maintain `rma.mv` model? Ie instead of moving from res1 to res2 parharps you might consider moving from res2 to res1

Comment: @Onyambu, oh! So there are a number of packages (e.g., `emmeans`; `effects`) that work with `lm()` but not `rma.mv()`. These packages only use the `coef` and `vcov()` of their input model. As a result, if I substitute the `coef` and `vcov()` of an lm, I can get the results for the rma.mv(). Does that help?

Comment: It seems you have a further analysis. There is no way to change that. why? because even after changing the class etc. functions like `.vcov.aliased` which is used to compute the `vcov` for `lm` will still consider the `vcov(res2)` instead of `vcov(res)`. You just need to think of the question in a different way. The notion of further analysis of the `lm` object makes it impractical to just replace the vcov/ coeffs. The class of `res2` as long as it remains to be `lm` then even including the attribute wont impact the results

Comment: @Onyambu, there is another function `nlme::gls()` that works great (see [HERE](https://github.com/rnorouzian/s/blob/main/mmm.R#L1287)). There is just one problem. Unlike `lm()`, `gls()` can't handle situations where some coefs are NA. I may ask a new question about that, while lm() will return `NA` for such rank deficiencies.

Comment: I see. Let me take a look at this question. Hopefully will find something to post as an answer

Comment: In case, a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70707278/16762740) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you are planning to use the result of the `vcov()` call, and that's crucial.  If all you are doing is calling `vcov()` and you want a different result, simply put the `metafor` object as an attribute of the `lm` object, assign it a new class (say "lmPlusMetafor"), and define a `vcov.lmPlusMetafor` method to extract the result from the `metafor` part.

Here is the code to do this:

```
library(metafor)

dat2 <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=waward, n1i=wtotal, ci=maward,
n2i=mtotal, data=dat.bornmann2007)

res1 <- rma.mv(yi ~ 0+type, vi, random = ~ 1 | study/obs, data=dat2)

res2 <- lm(yi ~ 0+type, data = dat2)

attr(res2, "metafor") <- res1

class(res2) <- c("lmWithMetafor", class(res2))

vcov.lmWithMetafor <- function(object, ...) vcov(attr(object, "metafor"))
```

Now when you run `vcov(res1)` or `vcov(res2)` you'll get the same result.

However, this is probably not good enough for anything useful.  For example, if you now run `summary(res2)`, I think you'll see standard errors etc. based on the original values, not the metafor ones.

If you want everything to work, you'll need a lot more changes:  you'll need to see how the things you want are calculated, and work out how to do them with this new `"lmWithMetafor"` object.  It won't be easy.

Comment: Can you please share your first, simpler solution?

Comment: I have now done that, but I don't think it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will satsify what you need, but assigning the function `vcov` to an object may help?

```
vcov_1 <- vcov(res1)
vcov_2 <- vcov(res2)   

vcov_1 <- vcov_2
```

```
> vcov_1 <- vcov(res1)
> vcov_1
               typeFellowship    typeGrant
typeFellowship   0.0018436986 0.0000618297
typeGrant        0.0000618297 0.0014597749

> vcov_2 <- vcov(res2) 
> vcov_2
               typeFellowship  typeGrant
typeFellowship    0.008567784 0.00000000
typeGrant         0.000000000 0.00556906


> vcov_1 <- vcov_2
> vcov_1
               typeFellowship  typeGrant
typeFellowship    0.008567784 0.00000000
typeGrant         0.000000000 0.00556906
```

Comment: Was there a purpose of `vcov_1<- vcov(res1)`?? just do `vcov_1 <- vcov(res2)`.

Comment: Yes I noticed just at this moment. You are right. I wanted to show the steps I was thinking of. But I am not sure whether this is what the OP wants. Unfortunately I did not found an access with `res1$...` to `vcov()`.

Comment: That is because `vcov` computes its values on the fly from the summary of the model. The best option is for OP to compute `vcov(res1)` whenever he needs `vcov(res2)` or rather, store `vcov(res1)` and use it as needed